Unwanted line appears on the semicircle when zooming in on the page
When I zoomed in on the page (it was at 67 percent), I observed that an unwanted straight line appeared at the top of the semicircle. Normally, it does not occur at 100% appearance. I expect such a line not to appear when zooming in or out.
with zoom:

without zoom:

What causes this and how do I fix it? I was also expecting a semicircle shape as seen in the images, but a complete semicircle was not formed.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Header with Half Circle</title>
  <style>
    .header {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 12rem;
      background-color: #004d40;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .line {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 0.25em;
      background-color: white;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .half-circle {
      position: relative;
      width: 10rem;
      height: 5rem;
      background-color: #004d40;
      border: 0.25em solid white;
      border-top: none;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;
      z-index: 2;
      transform: translateY(50%);
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="header">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="half-circle"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>



Is it possible to find such a header ready-made?

Clear the transform of the half-circle and position it as absolute, the same as line.
transform is based own element itsself
when you use absolute and position, place the element on the parent basis.
If you position them on the same basis, there will be no subtle differences.
And for border, please check this.
Border-radius in percentage (%) and pixels (px) or em


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Header with Half Circle</title>
  <style>
    .header {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 12rem;
      background-color: #004d40;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .line {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 0.25em;
      background-color: white;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .half-circle {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      width: 10rem;
      height: 5rem;
      background-color: #004d40;
      border: 0.25em solid white;
      border-top: none;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border-radius: 0 0 5rem 5rem;
      z-index: 2;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="header">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="half-circle"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>



